# How do I set the background and foreground colors in a WPF DataGrid GroupStyle's Expander?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, expander

I have a WPF DataGrid with DataGrid.GroupStyle defined.

How do I set the background and foreground (text) colors for the controls contained within the Expander?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how you are grouping. Post related XAML and VM code

Answer (score 0):

Define a style for GroupHeader :

```
<window.resources>
  <style x:key="GroupHeaderStyle" targettype="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
            Background="White"
            Foreground="Black">
            <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                      Background="Blue"
                      Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </Expander>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </style>  
</window.resources>
```

And use defined style in Datagrid

```
    <Custom:DataGrid x:Name="dgData" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <Custom:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Custom:DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </Custom:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact" Binding="{Binding Contact}"/>
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Email ID" Binding="{Binding EmailID}"/>
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
        </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
    </Custom:DataGrid>
```

I have used Background="White"
            Foreground="Red" for Grouping Bar but you can use as per your choice